# Creating custom Label in C# and passing data in events

Tags: c#, events, label

I had been playing around with an idea for a game, and implementation was going fairly well, but I have hit a stumbling block.

Basically, I have a form, which will show talent trees.  I am just going to use labels to display the relevant details, and I want to create them programmatically.  The display part is working fine, the part I am having trouble with is adding an event handler to the labels.

I want to be able to pass data during the event handling, so that I can identify which specific label was clicked, but I am hitting a brick wall.  So when a particular label is clicked, the name of its associated skill (just passing a string) will be sent to the event handler.  Any help would be appreciated.  Here is the relevant code that I have:

```
        public void DisplayTree()
    {
        int i=0;
        startPoint.X = 40;
        startPoint.Y = 125;

        foreach(SkillNode s in tree.tier1)
        {
            for (i=0; i < s.labels.Count;i++ )
            {
                //Displays a label for each available rank for a skill
                s.labels.ElementAt(i).Text = (i+1).ToString()+"/"+s.maxRank.ToString();
                s.labels.ElementAt(i).Location = startPoint;
                startPoint.Y += s.labels.ElementAt(i).Height + 2;
                s.labels.ElementAt(i).Name = "lbl"+s.name+i.ToString();

                //Only enable it to be clicked if the user is at the correct rank
                if (s.rank == i)
                {
                    s.labels.ElementAt(i).Enabled = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    s.labels.ElementAt(i).Enabled = false;
                }
                //Add Event here
                //I want to pass the name of the skill with the event

                this.Controls.Add(s.labels.ElementAt(i));
            }
            startPoint.X += s.title.Width + 5;
            startPoint.Y = 125;
        }
    }
    public void LabelClick()
    {
        //Code here to pick out the name of the label


    }
```

Comment: If you attach a `Click` handler to a label, then the first argument is usually `sender` which is _the object that sent the event_.

Comment: Thanks for replying Matt.  I initially had that, but I couldn't add a custom piece of data to it.  Is there a way to attach an additional piece of data?

Comment: Both Winforms and WPF controls have a `Tag` property that you can assign any arbitrary object to. Note, however, this is not a particularly good way to do these things. The right way is with data binding and having an MVC or MVVM model. But that's beyond the scope of a simple answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    public void LabelClick()
    {
       Console.WriteLine(((Control)sender).Name);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I will be able to use this to make things work.

Answer (score 0):

When you create an event and want to follow the official C# styleguide, you follow the following pattern:

```
public delegate void {YourName}EventHandler(object sender, {YourName}EventArgs args);
public event {YourName}EventHandler EventName;
```

Every information about what happened in the event or can be manipulated by the subscriber is stored in a class that inherits `EventArgs`. The delegate also contains a reference to the sender, which is the object that fires the event.

When you fire an event you do the following, regularly in a protected method that has the same name as the Event with an "On" as prefix:

```
EventName?.Invoke(this, new {YourName}EventArgs() { Initialize Stuff });
```

As you can see, you can work with the `sender` and identify the object. In your case you could also change `object sender` to `UIElement sender` (or similar) to make it easier to identify stuff without a cast.